# AttributeError: ‘super’ object has no attribute ‘__getattr__’ [Troubleshooting: Kivy]

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd, mapview

I am creating an android application using kivy.garden.mapviev, I want the user to be able to move the marker (hero icon) with buttons. when I add an int value to the value dumped from string to float, I convert the result back to string. when i try to do this i get an error. I execute the entire application code in one file, screen manager is a string in the file as screen_helper

when i try to execute the code get the error given in the subject. I'm new to: kivy / kivyMD,
below application code and screenshots :.

```
screen_helper = """
ScreenManager:
    UsersPlayGameOnMap:
<UsersPlayGameOnMap>:
    name: 'screenmapmove'
    MapView:
        id: mapview
        lat: 40.41362602642995
        lon: -3.6819590868909984 
        zoom:19        
        max_zoom : 19
        min_zoom :19
        MapMarkerPopup:
            id: player_position
            source: "img/myicons/heromenuicon.png"
            lat: 40.41362602642995
            lon: -3.6819590868909984    
    MDIconButton :
        icon : "apps-box" 
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.1,'center_y':0.1}
        user_font_size : 40 
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'UserPlatformFunctions'
    MDIconButton : 
        id : up  
        icon : "arrow-up-bold-box-outline"       
        pos_hint : {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.18}
        user_font_size : 40 
        on_press: root.buttonUP()
    MDIconButton : 
        id : down 
        icon : "arrow-down-bold-box-outline"       
        pos_hint : {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.1}
        user_font_size : 40 
        on_press: root.button_DOWN()

    MDIconButton : 
        id : right 
        icon : "arrow-right-bold-box-outline"       
        pos_hint : {'center_x':0.65,'center_y':.1}
        user_font_size : 40 
        on_press: root.button_RIGHT()
    MDIconButton :
        id : left  
        icon : "arrow-left-bold-box-outline"       
        pos_hint : {'center_x':0.35,'center_y':0.1}
        user_font_size : 40 
        on_press: root.button_LEFT()

"""

LATI=40.41362602642995
LONDI=-3.6819590868909984
SETTING = True

class UsersPlayGameOnMap(Screen):


    def buttonUP(self):
        self.pressUP = True

        self.pressDOWN = False
        self.pressLEFT = False
        self.pressRIGHT = False

        self.LoadPlayerObject()


    def button_RIGHT(self):
        self.pressRIGHT = True

        self.pressDOWN = False
        self.pressUP = False
        self.pressLEFT = False

        self.LoadPlayerObject()


    def button_LEFT(self):
        self.pressLEFT = True

        self.pressRIGHT = False
        self.pressDOWN = False
        self.pressUP = False

        self.LoadPlayerObject()


    def button_DOWN(self):
        self.pressDOWN = True

        self.pressUP = False
        self.pressLEFT = False
        self.pressRIGHT = False

        self.LoadPlayerObject()


    def LoadPlayerObject(self):

        if SETTING == False:
            self.player_pos_pion = self.localpion
            self.player_pos_poz = self.localpoz


        if SETTING == True:
            self.ids.mapview.lat = LATI
            self.ids.mapview.lon = LONDI
            self.player_pos_pion = LATI
            self.player_pos_poz = LONDI
            self.SETTING = False

        longitude = float(self.player_pos_poz)
        latitude = float(self.player_pos_pion)

        if self.pressUP == True:
             latitude +=0.001

        if self.pressDOWN == True:
            latitude -=0.001

        if self.pressLEFT == True:
            longitude -=0.0001

        if self.pressRIGHT == True:
            longitude +=0.0001

        self.localpoz = longitude
        self.localpion = latitude
        self.PLAYER_POSITION()


    def PLAYER_POSITION(self):

        my_lat = NumericProperty(self.localpion)
        my_lon = NumericProperty(self.localpoz)

        playerpos = App.get_running_app().root.ids.player_position
        playerpos.lat = NumericProperty(my_lat)
        playerpos.lon = NumericProperty(my_lon)
        mapposition = App.get_running_app().root.ids.mapview
        mapposition.center_on(my_lat,my_lon)


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(UsersPlayGameOnMap(name='screenmapmove'))

class gameapp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return self.screen


gameapp().run()
```

[image: Screen]

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you are trying to access the `player_position` (and later, the `mapview`) ids in the `root` widget of your `App`, which is the `ScreenManager`. But those ids are defined in the rule for the `UsersPlayGameOnMap`, so that is where those ids are. To access those ids, you need to do it through your instance of `UsersPlayGameOnMap`. Something like this:

```
    game_screen = MDApp.get_running_app().root.get_screen('screenmapmove')
    playerpos = game_screen.ids.player_position
    .
    .
    .
    mapposition = game_screen.ids.mapview
```

In that same code, you have a problem with your use of `NumericProperty`. `Properties` should be defined inside a class, but outside of any method. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html).